# Twitter Bootstrap 2 on collapse event

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, dhtml, twitter-bootstrap-2

is there any way to catch when the collapse menu appears (or when collapse button is clicked by user) ?

i'm using standard bootstrap twitter framework and classes.

Comment: You want to catch the collapse event on your whole document or just a section/specific menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TWITTER BOOTSTRAP 2**

It looks like the plugin is adding the class "in" to the active collapse group. So maybe you could do something like.

```
if( $('#collapseOne').hasClass('in') ){
..do something
}
```

EDIT:

Okay, I don't have anyway of testing right now, so these are kind of just guesses. I am sure you could easily determine when a collapse link was clicked by doing this.

```
$('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){
   console.log('clicked');
});
```

However if you wanted to know exactly which one was clicked you would probably have to index them.

Comment: BS 3.0 has four events `show.bs.collapse`, `shown.bs.collapse`, `hide.bs.collapse` and `hidden.bs.collapse`

Answer (score 34):

In bootstrap 3.x, the four events you're looking for are:

```
show.bs.collapse
shown.bs.collapse
hide.bs.collapse
hidden.bs.collapse
```

They fire on the data-target DOM element, e.g. for the following mark-up:

```
<div role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Title</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li id="item1"><a href="#item1">Menu Item 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You'd listen (in jQuery) via:

```
$('.navbar-collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() { alert('shown'); });
$('.navbar-collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() { alert('hidden'); });
```

Comment: The questioner is looking for help with Bootstrap 2, not 3

Answer (score 9):

Use the "shown" event handler:

```
$("#accordion").on("shown",function(event){
        collapse_element = event.target;
    });
```

Refer to:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse to see the other events supported

Comment: Unfortunately though I successfully got an accordion with this event working in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RobbSadler/Td47n/) it doesn't seem to want to work in Bootstrap 3.0, and the link provided is now broken. Continuing on the search...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use easing animation with the changing of the icon you need to do this on show/hide.

In this example, I'm using bootstrap 2.3.2, jQuery 1.8.3, and Font Awesome 3.2.1

HTML:

```
<div id="accordion" class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a data-item-id="{id}" href="#something" data-parent="#accordion"
         data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle">
       <i class="icon icon-expand-alt"></i> {title}</a>
     </div>
     <div data-item-id="{id}" class="accordion-body collapse" id="something">
       <div class="accordion-inner">
         {Content}
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
 ... {additional panels}
</div>
```

js:

```
$('#accordion').on('show hide', function (e) {
  var oTarget = $(e.target);
  var oIcon = $('i', $('a[data-item-id="' + oTarget.attr('data-item-id') + '"]'));
  oIcon.toggleClass('icon-expand-alt icon-collapse-alt', 200);
 });
```